# The Culture Picker does not afect on navigation links in Orchard CMS website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

When we use the `Culture Picker` module to create multilanguage website, we create some translates to content items, to do it.

For example i have two pages, `AboutUS-ENG` and `AboutUS-FA`. first one is for English and the second one is Persian version of same page. Also the routes of the pages are different (`/AboutUS-ENG` and `/AboutUS-FA`).

In my site i have navigation menu that it contains some links which refers some page like `/AboutUS-ENG` when the English culture is selected.

Now the problem is that when i change current Culture to Persian from Culture Picker combo box, it should be change to Persian one (`/AboutUS-FA` instead of `/AboutUS-ENG`).
But it does not do that and shows a link to `/AboutUS-ENG`.

How can i solve the problem? Any idea please?
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of menu items do you use in the navigation menu?

Comment: I create a Content Link which is built-in (Core.Navigation) on orchard . when on creating a page i check 'Add on a menu' and specify a text and publish it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the localization module.
Then you can add the "localization" part to the "page" content type.

Once this is done, there is a new link called "+ New translation" shown in the edit form of a page.

You can create a page (for example in English) and then edit this page and create a translation of this page by clicking on the link. Then you create a second page in Persian that is a linked translation of the English page.

Orchard should automatically switch to the localized page when you use the culture picker now.

In addition, menus can't be localized (yet) in orchard. Here's the workaround:

- You have to create 2 different menus (one in English and one in Persian).
- You have to enable the "Culture layer" module
- You create 2 layers, one for English and one for Persian (see documentation for the culture layer module)
- You add the English menu to the English layer and the Persian menu to the Persian layer

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did this but when i change site Default Site Culture i always get the same language pages. In my case, i added en-US culture to my es-UY site and i cant see en-US culture in front pages. Any clue ?